# Displaying Correct Time When In DST Or Not

Tags: javascript, date, scheduler, dst

I'm storing a schedule start time UTC, with the following information, Start hour, start minute and the day it is to trigger on. The issue I'm having is if I set a start time for 9AM, then I want 9AM to be shown all year, but I've noticed if DST comes into effect this isn't the case and I might see 8AM. Using Javascript, is there anyway I could ensure the correct time is shown regardless of DST? Would I need to store more information other than what I have mentioned above, to do this?

I've been playing around with the getTimezoneOffset() which returns the difference in minutes between local time and UTC, to see if I can offset correctly but having no luck, so wondering what is a recommeded implementation for this kind of scenario. I think Outlook stores the time zone along with it's scheduled time, so I'm thinking is that what I need to do.

Comment: Show some code, as UTC time doesn't contain DST.

Comment: I don't see how what you describe can happen. A date is a particular point in time and will not not change timezone. If it's a 9AM in June, it's going to show 9AM regardless of what time it's now. Similarly, 9AM in December will not shift to a 10AM at any point.

Comment: The scheduler can be enabled by different users in different timeszones, so to manage this I convert local to UTC time, so that under the hood it will alway run at the same time. If I convert the current local time that is not in DST, to utc, but then convert that value back on the UI, when in DST, it will be off by an hour, because the getTimezoneOffset will return a different value. I'll try post up some code in a while, will need to tidy it up first.

Comment: Fundamentally, you should just be taking whatever the local time would be for that date and storing it as UTC. If a user makes a schedule for 9AM in June, assuming they are in central Europe (+02:00 at that time), you store `2020-06-01T07:00:00Z`. If they select 9AM in December (+01:00 at the time), that would be `2020-12-01T08:00:00Z`. I'm not sure where and why you're doing an extra conversion but it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @VLAZ—I imagine the OP has situations like "set a meeting for 9:00 on the first Monday of each month". So the local offset matters, just working with the initial offset and UTC doesn't cut it.

Comment: The best way is to not use Date objects, as they are just an offset from the ECMAScript epoch and nothing more, they don't have a timezone. Far better to store events with metadata containing a description or timestamp that includes the method of calculating the event times, e.g. "09:00 every Monday in Africa/Djibouti". Or you can store the date, time and IANA location as separate fields and calculate dates as required. A library like Luxon will really help with that.